# Update the contents of a textbox which is bound to a datasource depending on the value which is put into the textbox by the datasource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7, if-statement

I have a text box which is bound to a data service to get its contents. At the moment the data service puts a number between 1 and 9 into that text box. What I need to do is based on that value replace the contents of that text box with a string. So for example if the original contents of the textbox was "1" instead it would be replaced with "1 - Example text here"

Below is the code where the text box is defined.

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category3}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I thought that possibly I would use an else if statement but I don't know how to reference the textblock from within that if statement.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the TextBlock so it can ve referenced by the code behind so something like the code below will work

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="tb1" Text="{Binding Category1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>

if (tb1.Text == "something")
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
        else
        {
            DoSomethingElse();
        }
```

Comment: Ah ok I see where my problem is now, I was tring to do this, but does it make a difference that my textBlock is in a list box as its telling me that " the name "tbl1" does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

You can define a value converter. For example:

```
public class IntToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from int to Text
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from Text to int
    }
}

<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.Window1"
    ...
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <my:IntToTextConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text={Binding Category1, Converter={StaticResource converter}}/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

There is a good article about value converters [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)